# Ways to add multiple value to response headers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, http-headers, cache-control

There is a confusion in setting multiple values to the headers  according to RFC2616, the response header values should be **comma separated**, but when i look at certain headers they are semicolon separated for example in the w3 site if you see the response header "content-type" its a **semi-colon** separated value.
[w3 site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIkIa.png)  .
If semicolon is accepted then ,
the second question is when we cache-control with semicolon separated values the cache-control does not behave correctly in chrome but works fine in fire fox.
For Example ,consider the following image [cachecontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6kw9.png) the values are semicolon separated and the behavior that is expected  and working in firefox is it should not cache the page but chrome defies this and caches the page. Any help on clarification is highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard for adding multiple values of a single HTTP Header to a request or response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096888/standard-for-adding-multiple-values-of-a-single-http-header-to-a-request-or-resp)

Comment: HTTP headers are comma-separated. See [the spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) for what the semicolon means in `Content-Type`. If Firefox accepts semicolon-separated values, it's a bug. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163030/cache-control-headers-no-longer-interpreted-properly-in-chromium-93) for a case where Chrome got stricter, and why you shouldn't rely on non-spec behaviour.

Comment: @Joe - Thanks for the reply ,the link that you have given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163030/cache-control-headers-no-longer-interpreted-properly-in-chromium-93 really helped thanks !